# Integrating Whitebox GAT (free and open) with ArcMap UI?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, .net, open-source-gis, whitebox-gat, integration

[image: Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools]

I wrote a number of ArcGIS VBA automations in grad school; however, they're fully dependent on the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension, which is not only closed-source but expensive to the point of deterrence.

Since VBA is deprecated and since some researchers at the U still use my VBA tools, I thought it would be fun to rewrite them in .Net. But now, with more experience, I further realize it would be more appropriate for academic use if those utilities consumed open algorithms.

With this in mind, I'm considering [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/) as a potential stand-in for the Spatial Analyst hydrology tools, and I'm curious if there are any success stories or time-saving "gotchas" related to ArcGIS/Whitebox integration.

I anticipate several folks will want to counter-suggest implementing Saga, GRASS, R, et cetera. If this is your position, please describe why pursuing a Whitebox integration would be unwise. For example, does it only support a few input formats, has it poor handling of large (1-2 GB+) files, etc.

---

I did some playing around with the Whitebox UI, and [with the help of their tutorials](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/tutorials.html), it wasn't difficult to pre-process a 30-meter DEM I had laying around. Next, after lining-up the hydro rasters, I created a pour point and rendered its watershed. This was enough to get a feel for the Whitebox user experience.

Whitebox is extendable and/or consumable using .Net or Python. Having accomplished some basics in the Whitebox UI, I thought I'd chain together the typical DEM pre-processing tasks with a simple .Net automation (no ArcMap just yet). DEM pre-processing usually means the following:

1. set no data value (Whitebox needs this, but Arc never did)
2. fill sinks
3. create a flow direction raster
4. create a flow accumulation raster

I put together the following Windows Form "application" (aka `WhiteboxDaisyChain`). It takes a system directory containing an ArcGIS Grid (.FLT) and performs the tasks noted above. If you want to try this, you'll need to [download the compiled binaries](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml), unzip, then copy all the `.dll` files from `..\WhiteboxGAT_1_0_7\Plugins` into your project -- I put everything in `..\WhiteboxDaisyChain\Whitebox`. However, this example only needs the four `DLLs` mentioned at the top of the code sample.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// 1) Create a new Windows Form
// 2) Put all these in a Whitebox folder in the C# project root.
// 3) Add project references to the following and create using statements:

using Interfaces;       // requires Add Reference: Interfaces.dll
using ImportExport;     // requires Add Reference: ImportExport.dll
using ConversionTools;  // requires Add Reference: ConversionTools.dll
using flow;             // requires Add Reference: flow.dll


namespace WhiteboxDaisyChain
{
    // 4) Prepare to implement the IHost interface.
    // 5) Right-click IHost, select "Implement interface.."
    public partial class UI : Form, IHost
    {

        // 6) Add a BackgroundWorker object.
        private BackgroundWorker worker;

        public UI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // 7) Instantiate the worker and set "WorkerReportsProgress".
            worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }


        // 8) Use some event to set things in motion.. i.e. Button click.
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressLabel.Text = "Running..";

            // This is the path containing my ArcGrid .FLT.
            // All processing will unfold to this directory.
            string path = "C:\\xData\\TutorialData\\DemWhitebox\\";

            string[] fltArgs = new string[1];
            fltArgs[0] = path + "greene30.flt";                 // in: Arc floating point grid

            // creates a raster in Whitebox data model
            ImportArcGrid importAG = new ImportArcGrid();
            importAG.Initialize(this as IHost);
            importAG.Execute(fltArgs, worker);                  // out:  path + "greene30.dep"

            // set the nodata value on the DEM
            string[] noDataArgs = new string[2];
            noDataArgs[0] = path + "greene30.dep";              // in: my raw DEM
            noDataArgs[1] = "-9999";                            // mine used -9999 as nodata value

            SetNoData setNoData = new SetNoData();
            setNoData.Initialize(this as IHost);
            setNoData.Execute(noDataArgs, worker);              // out:  path + "greene30.dep"

            // fill sinks in the DEM
            string[] fillSinksArgs = new string[4];
            fillSinksArgs[0] = path + "greene30.dep";           // in: my DEM with NoData Fixed
            fillSinksArgs[1] = path + "greene30_fill.dep";      // out: my DEM filled
            fillSinksArgs[2] = "50";                            // the dialog default
            fillSinksArgs[3] = "0.01";                          // the dialog default

            FillDepsBySize fillSinks = new FillDepsBySize();
            fillSinks.Initialize(this as IHost);
            fillSinks.Execute(fillSinksArgs, worker);

            // create a flow direction raster
            string[] flowDirArgs = new string[2];
            flowDirArgs[0] = path + "greene30_fill.dep";        // in: my Filled DEM
            flowDirArgs[1] = path + "greene30_dir.dep";         // out: flow direction raster

            FlowPointerD8 flowDirD8 = new FlowPointerD8();
            flowDirD8.Initialize(this as IHost);
            flowDirD8.Execute(flowDirArgs, worker);

            // create a flow accumulation raster
            string[] flowAccArgs = new string[4];
            flowAccArgs[0] = path + "greene30_dir.dep";         // in: my Flow Direction raster
            flowAccArgs[1] = path + "greene30_acc.dep";         // out: flow accumulation raster
            flowAccArgs[2] = "Specific catchment area (SCA)";   // a Whitebox dialog input
            flowAccArgs[3] = "false";                           // a Whitebox dialog input

            FlowAccumD8 flowAccD8 = new FlowAccumD8();
            flowAccD8.Initialize(this as IHost);
            flowAccD8.Execute(flowAccArgs, worker);

            progressLabel.Text = "";
            progressLabel.Text = "OLLEY-OLLEY-OXEN-FREE!";
        }



        /* IHost Implementation Methods Below Here */

        public string ApplicationDirectory
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public void ProgressBarLabel(string label)
        {
            this.progressLabel.Text = "";
            this.progressLabel.Text = label;                    // This is the only one I used.
        }

        public string RecentDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public bool RunInSynchronousMode
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void RunPlugin(string PluginClassName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SetParameters(string[] ParameterArray)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ShowFeedback(string strFeedback, string Caption = "GAT Message")
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

So far I'm digging this, but I don't yet have a real success story or any show-stoppers to describe.. My next goal will be interactively submitting pour points from ArcMap. Basically, I want to click the map ..get the watershed.

Comment: I just wanted to point out the the latest versions of Whitebox allow you to digitize a shapefile pour point on-screen to input to the watershed tool. It works quite well. JL

Comment: @JohnLindsay, hey there, I recognize you as the Guelph professor who created Whitebox. When I started this thread back in Jan 2012, Whitebox was written in .Net, but now it's in Java I understand. I've considered deleting this thread as irrelevant, since the .Net stuff isn't maintained, but if the old release is still available, even unmaintained, it's still valuable. I had thought about creating a mobile app for floating enthusiasts that consumed Whitebox in .Net WebServices, but I've since tabled that idea. Have I overlooked an "archives" among the downloads?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to consider other applications outside of Spatial Analyst, you might consider looking into the the [SEXTANTE library](http://www.sextantegis.com/).  While I have not personally used it, if you watch this [video clip](http://sextantegis.blogspot.com/2011/08/first-video-of-sextante-for-arcgis.html), you can see that they demonstrate ways to work with rasters.

Why might you consider this toolset?  They already have built the "[SEXTANTE for ArcGIS extension](http://www.sextantegis.com/arcgis.html)" (free), which allows users to consume SEXTANTE tools in ArcMap.

Comment: That's a nice tip, I'll look into it.

Comment: Note, SEXTANTE for ArcGIS doesn't exist anymore.  See [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/34278/7424).